# Shape gradient multi in android xml

Tags: android, xml

how to make multiple shapes like I drew.

[image: the desired shape][1]

this my base_shape.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
  >
    <gradient android:angle="0"
        android:startColor="#70B0EE"
        android:endColor="#6A92F0" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:topRightRadius="8dp"
        />
</shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="200dp" >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle>
        <gradient android:angle="0"
            android:startColor="#B0C7DD"
            android:endColor="#6A92F0" />
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="8pt"
            android:topLeftRadius="130pt"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>.
```

and this my_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/base_shape"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ln1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a problem, the top right radius is not working, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information to answer your question but I am trying my best here, the view mainly should be a constraint layout within you can put the image and the title and everything, on the right side, I think what you are struggling with is the other gradient, it would work as an imageView holding image with alpha on the main constraint layout with constraint to the right side with no margin it will get you the desired result

[image]